# Caching java method

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I want to cache heavy method result, but I for some reason it would not store in cache.

I had tried to use spring cache but it only worked when caching whole api where I only need to cache part of it.

```
@ResponseBody
public Person validateTest(@Param("name") String name) {
    return cache(name);
}

@Cacheable(value = "getName", key = "#name")
public Person cache(String name) {
    Person person = generateString(name);
    return person;
}


public Person generateString(String name) {
    System.out.println("generating");
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(name);
    return person;
}



@Data
class Person implements Serializable { 
   private String name;
}
```

[StackTrace of requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Z8c.png)

*@EnableCaching* is enabled

Comment: Can you explain how the above solution did not work? do you have errors or just the method is still being executed every time instead of hitting cache?

Comment: It's executed every time it is runned

Comment: have you enabled caching by `@EnableCaching` to one of your configuration classes?

Comment: I enabled at **@SpringBootApplication** class

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the cached method directly here, this doesn't work (the documentation is hardly clear about it).  Refactor your code so the `@Cacheable` method is in a different bean, then inject that bean (which will actually be wrapped in a proxy so it can do the caching), then call it.